# I am trying to convert a dynamic formula in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

this is not a regular JS tasks as I need help with JS and maths little bit. I got the math formula done but now I'm trying to get it in javascript.

I writing a calculator so I got var a,b,c and D.

D is the sum of A,B,C (Currently it is 825)

I changed the D from  825 to 600 so everything should reduce propotionaly but not B. B should stay as it is and A and C should reduce.

The following code below calculate correctly but I want to make it dynamic fully. Var newA and newC I can't seem to get the right variable in it as I need the newA to dive by 6 and New C to divide by 5/6.

Is there any genius good in math and javascript?
I also attached an image of the math formula if anyone can maybe write a better JS. 
[image]
The idea is if that I can after add more variables and when I reduce the D it will let me know how much are the elements that can be reduced.

Here is the code:

```
// Variables
var a = 100; 
var b = 225; // this variable does not change.
var c = 500;

// Container sum
var containerSum = a + b + c ;

// New container sum
var newContainerSum = 600;

//  825 - (100 + 500) = 225
var fixedElement = b;

// 600 - 225 = 375
var remainingElementsTotal = newContainerSum - fixedElement;

//Propotion calculate 100/500 = 1/5 = 0.2
var propotions = a/c;
var remainingPropotions = 1 - propotions;


var newA = remainingElementsTotal/6;  
var newC = remainingElementsTotal * (5/6);
```

Comment: So in your equation will B always be fixed? For example: a+b+c+d+e=D

Comment: Yes  B is always fixed. that;s the tricky part.

Comment: You have already written logic. Which will lead you to correct result.what do you want to acheive then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general function that takes the original array of values (`vals`), the index of the fixed value (`fixedIndex`), and the new sum (`newSum`); and  returns a new array with suitably modified values:

```
function calc(vals, fixedIndex, newSum) {
  var initSum = vals.reduce(function (prev, cur) {return prev + cur;}, 0);
  var fixedElement = vals[fixedIndex];
  var initRemainingSum = initSum - fixedElement;
  var endRemainingSum = newSum - fixedElement;
  return vals.map(function(cur, index) {return index === fixedIndex ? cur : endRemainingSum*(cur/initRemainingSum);})
}
```

For example:

```
calc([100, 225, 500], 1, 600)
```

returns:

```
[ 62.5, 225, 312.5 ]
```

[EDITED]

To answer your follow-on question in the comments, if you want to specify an array of fixed indices (`fixedIndices`), this should work:

```
function calc2(vals, fixedIndices, newSum) {
  var initSum = vals.reduce(function (prev, cur) {return prev + cur;}, 0);
  var fixedSum = fixedIndices.reduce(function (prev, cur, index) {return prev + vals[cur];}, 0);
  var initRemainingSum = initSum - fixedSum;
  var endRemainingSum = newSum - fixedSum;
  return vals.map(function(cur, index) {return fixedIndices.indexOf(index) === -1 ? endRemainingSum*(cur/initRemainingSum) : cur;})
}
```

For example:

```
calc2([100, 225, 500], [1,2], 600)
```

returns:

```
[ -125, 225, 500 ]
```

Comment: question what do I do when I got several fixed variables? how do i update the fixedIndex?

Comment: change `index === fixedIndex` to `fixedIndices.indexOf(index)!==-1`

Comment: If I change calc([100, 225, 500], 1, 600) to calc([100, 225, 500], [1,2], 600) than i get NAN,

Uncaught ReferenceError: fixedIndices is not defined

Comment: @ChrisGuru: I have edited my answer to include a function that works for any number of fixed indices.

Comment: I assume I can use the other func for 1 fixed or several ? If it takes two than it can also take one right?

Comment: The `fixedIndices ` array passed to `calc2` can contain any number of elements (even none). (The elements must be valid indices for the `vals` array, without any duplicates.)

Comment: @cyberSam, i know this is more to the question than I asked, but is there any chance you could help modify you script so that I have a working an example as per the question? I have tried to modify your script to have two vals  and can get the logic how you got the output,  In my return the proportions are wrong.

Comment: `wrapperWidths` is not defined in your new code snippet. How is that defined? Maybe that is (part of) the problem? If you need more help, you will need to explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you seeking for.

```
var elements = [100, 300, 225, 560, 900],newElements=[];
var containerSum = elements.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur;
});
var newContainerSum = 1500;
var indexToBeFixed = 1;
var remainingElementsTotal = newContainerSum - elements[indexToBeFixed];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  newElements.push(i !== indexToBeFixed?(elements[i] * remainingElementsTotal) / (containerSum - elements[indexToBeFixed]):elements[i] );
}

console.log(newElements);

/*
[ 67.22689075630252,
  300,
  151.26050420168067,
  376.47058823529414,
  605.0420168067227 ]
*/
```

> **Update**
>
> elements array will be modified.

Comment: i have Updated the answer

Comment: I am trying to assigned the changed variable to  back to the element without the last one in the array

Comment: @ChrisGuru
Yes i have done the same....!
Do you want to preserve the original elements?

Comment: both the solutions are same except preserving the original array.

Comment: Thank you both for help, i couldn't have solved it without u